# popup hovers with cursor

Tags: css, popup, cursor, imagemap

for a project I'm working on I use a worldmap image, and centered this image.
the idea is that if you go over a certain country a tool tip message will come up below it and tell you the name of the country.
the popup box is build in css.
for example:

```
span.Amerika:hover:after {
content: "Amerika";
position: absolute;
width: 80px; /* box size */
height: 20px; /* box size */
padding: 10px;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
color: rgb(113, 157, 171);
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border: 4px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
border-radius: 5px;
text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 1px 1px 1px;
box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0980392) 1px 1px 2px 0px;
top: 320px; /* positioning */
left: 320px; /* positioning */
}
```

you could have guessed the positioning only works on my screen. on all larger screens the boxes will appear somewhere else.
So I'm thinking about having the tool tip message hover with the cursor. (follow the cursor)
how would i do this?

Comment: So what is your question? : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Comment: So I'm thinking about having the tool tip message hover with the cursor. (follow the cursor) how would i do this?

Comment: http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/